# Sharepoint and Python3.7

Tags: python-3.x, sharepoint, python-requests

I'm trying to access an internal sharepoint and I haven't been able to figure out how to do it. I've seen some examples and came up with some code but I got a 401 error out of it. I obviously replace my USERNAME and PASSWORD with my actual credentials but I still got a 401. I'm attempts to access the SharePoint and grab lists of data (That span multiple pages). Right now I'm trying to just access the site and proceed from there.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
from requests_ntlm import HttpNtlmAuth

response = requests.get("http://share-internal.division.com/teams/alpha/Components/Lists/Types/AllItems.aspx", auth=HttpNtlmAuth('DOMAIN\\USERNAME','PASSWORD'))

print (response.status_code)
```

I also tried a Basic request such as

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

response = requests.get("http://share-internal.Server.com/teams/Beta/Components/Lists/Workt/AllItems.aspx", auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USERNAME, PASSWORD))

print (response.status_code)
```

Just to be honest: I censored some of the URL as to maintain privacy